# Why are the magically sealed doors in Fellglow Keep not working?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

At fellglow keep, there is a cellar door and a normal door near it with magic effect over it, as I searched at google images, it seems to be a "magically sealed door".

The point is, no matter I open or close them, nothing happens and the effect wont wear off... nothing will explode either, nothing at all happens... Also, one npc has interacted with the normal door before (not with the cellar door) but I saw nothing happening either...

I wonder if my installation is broken or they are supposed to be like that in some way; On google I did not find much info... Is this a broken thing?

Comment: Are you on the "Hitting the Books" quest?

Comment: no! you mean these may work when that quest is active?

Answer (score 4):

As Raven Dreamer indicated in the comments, the College of Winterhold quest '[Hitting the Books](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hitting_the_Books)' takes place in Fellglow Keep.

Based on my experience, and on the [UESP article for this zone](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fellglow_Keep):

> Part of Fellglow Keep and all of Fellglow Keep Ritual Chamber are only accessible during the Hitting the Books quest.

You'll therefore need to start this quest - and, by extension, the preceding quests in the College of Winterhold questline (namely '[First Lessons](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:First_Lessons)' followed by '[Under Saarthal](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Under_Saarthal)') - to access the sealed areas in Fellglow Keep.

Starting this quest will, to coin a phrase, open a lot of doors for you...

Comment: so, you mean to the sealed areas be actually sealed right? as currently they are easy to "break in" :), I am still far from that, havent initiated the 1st quest on the line either... I will see what happens and comeback, thx!

Comment: @AquariusPower That is correct.  Any place in Skyrim that's sealed and you can't see an obvious way to get in is usually meant for a quest.